# Webpack doesn't resolve imports of JSON files from D3 packages

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, d3.js

I have an Angular app built with Webpack that imports locale JSON files from the `d3-format` package:

```
import d3Format from "d3-format/locale/en-US.json";
```

This worked fine with D3 v5. But after upgrading to v7, I get the following error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'd3-format/locale/en-US.json'
```

The JSON file is still in the same location (and in fact the IDE resolves it correctly). But Webpack just doesn't find it when building the app. The main change that broke this import is that the `package.json` of `d3-format` now includes this bit (and if I remove it, the build works fine again!):

```
"exports": {
  ".": {
    "umd": "./dist/d3-format.min.js",
    "default": "./src/index.js"
  },
  "./locale/*": "./locale/*.json"
}
```

The import also works if I specify an import path like this:

```
import d3Format from "../../../../node_modules/d3-format/locale/en-US.json";
```

But this is ugly, I'd rather avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

After updating D3Js from v6 to v7, the following error appeared during compilation of my Angular project:

```
» require('d3-time-format/locale/en-US.json');
Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'd3-time-format/locale/en-US.json' ...
```

[NodeJs documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#subpath-patterns) for the "exports" key says:

> All instances of * on the right hand side will then be replaced with this value, including if it contains any / separators. This is a direct static matching and replacement without any special handling for file extensions.

[webpack doc](https://webpack.js.org/guides/package-exports/#general-syntax) says:

> For properties ending with `*`, `*` may take any value and any `*` in the property value is replaced with the taken value

I understand this as: everything that is matched with the `*` on the *"key side"* of the mapping is then expanded in place of `*` in the *"value side"* of the mapping.

In fact, **removing the extension from the path did satisfy the resolver** and I have now  `require("d3-time-format/locale/en-US")`, which I guess should also work when using ESM import statement.

---

Note: NodeJs doc mentions a mapping where the asterisk is followed with an extension suffix in the key side, saying «Including the "*.js" on both sides of the mapping restricts the exposed package exports to only JS files». e.g.:

```
"./features/*.js": "./src/features/*.js",
```

But this doesn't seem to apply for *.json* files. I tried to turn the exports pattern in d3-time-format's *package.json* to `"./locale/*.json": "./locale/*.json"` and left the path with the *.json* extension in the *require* call, but no luck, the error «Module not found: Error: Package path ./locale/en-US is not exported from package ...» is raised during compilation.

Comment: Unfortunately, removing the extension does not work with an import statement. But I tested replacing it with a require(), and indeed it works. I'm not sure I'll go with this approach though, as we use import across the whole project.